# How to disallow spaces with a regex pattern in a URL input?

Tags: html, regex, validation

I'm using the HTML input type and you know that the standard validation is very permissive.

Consider this markup:

```
<form>
    <input type="url" name="link" value="http://jsfiddle .net/" required>
        
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
</form>
```

I want to add a custom `pattern` attribute to check that the user **can't provide any space**.

```
<input type="url" name="link" pattern="what to do here?" required>
```

You can fork this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t6dtbhqo/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why not try pattern="[^\s]+"
please see this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/MaaVeeran/nwcz722w/) i think it is working

```
<form>
<input type="url" name="link" value="http://jsfiddle .net/" pattern="[^\s]+"  title="please dont use the white space :)" required>

<button type="submit">OK</button>
```

Comment: title="please dont use the white space :)" ...... and see this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/MaaVeeran/nwcz722w/)